# Json Response from server in table form into Android Recycler view

Tags: php, android, json, android-recyclerview, android-tablelayout

I am working on an app, in which I am fetching some data from the database using PHP as my backend. I have a JSON response which I want to fetch in recycler view into table layout form.

I have my JSON Response from PHP which contains data. My Json consist of two arrays one which contains columns name and one which contains column values. I want to show it in a table. I have Tried using Recycler view but I can't achieve what I want. Below is my JSON response.

```
[
    [
        {
            "column_name": "email"
        },
        {
            "column_name": "product_code"
        },
        {
            "column_name": "Shape"
        },
        {
            "column_name": "BaseColor"
        },
        {
            "column_name": "Size"
        },
        {
            "column_name": "Qty"
        },
        {
            "column_name": "TransNo"
        },
        {
            "column_name": "Supplier"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "column_value": "ht@t.com"
        },
        {
            "column_value": "BBAN0003"
        },
        {
            "column_value": " ELEPHANT"
        },
        {
            "column_value": " "
        },
        {
            "column_value": " 0"
        },
        {
            "column_value": " 1"
        },
        {
            "column_value": " TID00000163"
        },
        {
            "column_value": " ABDUL"
        },
        {
            "column_value": "ht@t.com"
        },
        {
            "column_value": "MAAR0043"
        },
        {
            "column_value": " REC"
        },
        {
            "column_value": " WHITE"
        },
        {
            "column_value": " 06X04"
        },
        {
            "column_value": " 1"
        },
        {
            "column_value": " TID00000075"
        },
        {
            "column_value": " SUNIL"
        }
    ]
]
```

I want to know is there any way I can show this response in a table in android studio with column_name and column_values.

Please help on this I am so frustrated on this, Any help will be highly appreciated.
THANKS !!!!

Comment: I think this is not a valid JSON

Comment: I checked my api on Postman and this is what i get @RamMohandubey

Comment: It's a valid JSON.@Ram Mohan dubey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to get the **JSONArray** from the response. After that, you have to create dynamic rows in **TableLayout**

Check out my sample code:

```
String astr="[" +
            "  [" +
            "    {" +
            "      \"column_name\": \"email\"" +
            "    }," +
            "    {" +
            "      \"column_name\": \"product_code\"" +
            "    }" +
            "   " +
            "  ]," +
            "  [" +
            "    {" +
            "      \"column_value\": \"ht@t.com\"" +
            "    }," +
            "    {" +
            "      \"column_value\": \"BBAN0003\"" +
            "    } " +
            "  ]" +
            "]";
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(astr);
        TableLayout ll = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.displayLinear);
        TextView tv;


        for (int i = 0; i <jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONArray Column= jsonArray.getJSONArray(i);
            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
                for (int j = 0; j < Column.length(); j++) {
                    TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    row.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    tv = new TextView(this);
   JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) Column.get(j);
                    if (i == 0) {
                        tv.setText(jsonObject.getString("column_name"));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                 tv.setText(jsonObject.getString("column_value"));
                    }
                    row.addView(tv);
                }
            ll.addView(row, i);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have dynamically added **ROWS** in TableLayout.

I hope, this will help you.

Happy Coding...

Comment: I am fetching data from server, so there is no need of using RecyclerVIew ??

Comment: hey @pratik i tried using this method, firstly I tried getting in a TOAST to check if it works well but the  error is expected begin object but was begin array

Comment: ` @GET("testing/getProductdetails.php")
    Call<JSONArray> getColumnNames(@Query("email") String email);`

Comment: this is what I am trying to get data in JSON array

Comment: You can  use String instead of JSONArray in Call<JSONArray>.

Comment: then what will I use at place of astr in JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(astr);

Comment: astr means string which are getting from api response.

Comment: after using String instead of JSONarray  it gives EXPECTED a string but was a BEGIN_OBJECT at line 2 column 2 path $

Comment: Can you please give me api so i can check it.

Comment: above is my error also yes i undestood your point but unable to get what should i pass at place of astr in my service ...... let edit your answer with what i tried

Comment: astr is the response of your service. This is a just one string variable which holds the response your service.

Comment: http://pksinghhps.000webhostapp.com/testing/getProductdetails.php?email=ht@t.com    this is my api

Comment: are you using retrofit for api calling in mobile app side ?

Comment: did you changed your api response json ?

Comment: no its changed. Check json which you had add in above question and api response which currently getting.

Comment: My answer is right but now API response has been changed so i can't help you. If you feel my answer is correct then accept it

Comment: hey, actually now I changed my response to a whole new thing, can you help me how to fetch it in tabular form .. and thanks for your efforst till now

Comment: Now, this is simple json.

Comment: hey thank you for all your help pratik, I found your answer very helpful so I am going to accept it.